# Automate builds of MobiStudio projects

Tags: eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

MobiStudio is an Eclipse plugin to develop mobile phone applications. 
The projects are written in mscript, and then need to be compiled into phone specific packages.

Has anyone already tackled this?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's not that difficult to use, and since the time of your posting, MobiStudio has matured.

What would you like to know?

Comment: I was wanting to know how people were setting up Continuous Integration builds, using CruiseControl.net or similar (jenkins?).